# Convert Array to String with Excel Formula, is it possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Convert Array to String with Excel Formula, is it possible?

I know how this would be done with VBA, but I have to share my workbook, and I have to assume that other people will not be able to enable VBA written by me.

For Example I have following array: `{ "a","b"}`  I would like my formula to output `ab`

Origianlly I was thinking about using `CONCATENATE({"a","b"})` but that resulted in `a`

Comment: This is too vague. [Edit] your question to elaborate. Use of code samples, formulas or screen shots would be very beneficial to helping you.

Comment: I provided a simple example. Thanks for the input @CharlieRB

Comment: This isn't easy to do with a formula - there is no native function in Excel that can concatenate a range or array - I assume that there might be more than 2 values?

Comment: Where do you have the array? What format is it in? On the sheet? The result of a formula?

Comment: Yes its actually a list with couple thousand items, I am getting it as a named range from someone else's workbook.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with formulas however, catting a list of over 1000 strings seems likely to exceed excel limits for strings or give an unwieldy result.
Caveat aside.

- Make a hidden worksheet called Zone or any other name you want.
- if named range you are getting is called "x" then in the A column put "Count" and then in the cell under it enter =counta(x) ' this gives us the size of the array.
- name the cell with the actual number "Cnt"
- then in the c column starting at c3 enter in "Data "  this is a header
- at c4 enter =index(x,1)
- at c5 and extend past size of possible range =+IF(ROW()>Cnt+3,"",C4&INDEX(x,ROW()-3))
- at d2 enter "Answer" and at d3 enter =+OFFSET($C$3,Cnt,0)
- name the d3 cell as Ans and you can use this where you need.
  possible mod is to add  a "," such as c4&","&index(x,row()-3))
  use a iferror instead of the if(row()>cnt+3 to mask errors
  if have copied the formula to 2000 cells, have a test if(cnt>2000,"Error named range too large - Call John Doe", "") to cause a error message to appear if underestimated the size of the named range.

Answer (score 1):

2020 Answer (actually post-2016 answer)

`=TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,{"a","b"})` will return "ab"

Old question, but came up high in my search results. Since 2016 Excel has a `TEXTJOIN()` function which takes a delimiter, an ignore blanks flag, and an array, range, list of cells, list of strings, etc.

For example, the following will return an ordered list of unique values from the range.

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE,SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A100)))`